# Click besides item in QColumnView row to trigger different Context Menu

Tags: python, qt, contextmenu, pyside

I would like to know how to handle a right mouse click besides an item even when on the same row.

### Description

Similar to how Windows Explorer behaves that when you don't right click on the *name* of the file but in the white area to the side of it (even in white area between *name* and e.g. *size* in detail view) it gives you the "folder" context menu as opposed to the "file" context menu.

### Implementation

I'm looking to implement this Context Menu functionality in a QColumnView. The columns in this view are actually *QListView* widgets. So it might be more related to how a QListView behaves.

This is what I have now:

```
model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
view = QtGui.QColumnView()
view.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(contextMenu)
```

With a context menu like this:

```
def contextMenu(point):
    index = view.indexAt(point)
    is_selection = index.isValid()
    if not is_selection:
        # Not a valid item. Let's check what "column" we're in
        # This is our "folder" context
        child = view.childAt(point)
        listView = child.parentWidget()
        index = listView.rootIndex()

    path = model.filePath(index)

    # Create the menu
    menu = QtGui.QMenu()   
    if is_selection:
        # An item was selected (file context menu)
        menu.addAction("Explore file...")
    else:
        # An item was not selected (folder context menu)
        menu.addAction("Explore folder...")

    # Show the menu
    globalPoint = self.browserView.mapToGlobal(point)
    action = menu.exec_(globalPoint)
```

The **problem** here is that *clicking anywhere on the full row will be considered "as the item"*. Whereas what I'm looking for is *clicking on an area without text/icon should not be considered a on the item*.

Funnily enough this image shows roughly what I mean:

[image: QColumnView]

The blue selection bar here does not span the entire row in the view. That blue area is what I want to find. Running my interface somehow triggers that selection on the entire row, not just around the size of the label/icon.

So right mouse clicking to the right side next to **Address** would trigger the "folder" functionality as opposed to the "file" functionality.